# babel-loader breaks the `this` variable in an npm package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I switched from `awesome-typescript-loader` to `babel-loader` and I've been getting this issue in an npm package we use - `lodash-inflection`.

`Uncaught TypeError: this.pluralize is not a function at pluralize (lodash-inflection.js:68)`

Below is a breakpoint between the broken (**left**) and the working one (**right**).

[image]

The  `this` variable in the `lodash-inflection.js` becomes  the `window` instead of the actual value expected by the package so the package does not work anymore.

Below are the changes to the `webpack.js`

### OLD

```
{
  test: /\.tsx?$/,
  exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
  loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
  options: {
    getCustomTransformers: isDev && path.join(__dirname, './webpack.ts-transformers.js')
  }
}
```

### NEW

```
{
  test: /\.tsx?$/,
  exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      presets: [
        ["@babel/preset-env", { modules: "false" }],
        ["@babel/preset-typescript", { "allExtensions": true, "isTSX": true }],
        "@babel/preset-react",
      ],
      plugins: [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator"
      ],
      env: {
        development: {
          plugins: [
            [
              "styled-components",
              {
                displayName: true
              }
            ]
          ]
        }, production: {
          plugins: [
            [
              "styled-components",
              {
                displayName: false
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }],
}
```

Most of the babel options I've seen are just like that. I also tried changing the order of the `presets`.

Comment: how are you calling the `pluralize` method?

Comment: `import { pluralize } from 'lodash-inflection';` and then `<>{pluralize(foo, bar)}</>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the `lodash-inflection` package, it seems that there's an [open issue](https://github.com/danhper/lodash-inflection/issues/11) with trying to import and use individual methods. Try importing the whole package instead:

```js
import inflection from 'lodash-inflection';
//...
inflection.pluralize(foo, bar);
```

Comment: It worked! Wow. I never though of doing that since I've been thinking maybe the fix would be in webpack. I've seen that open issue but didn't think it's related. Any idea why it's working fine with `awesome-typescript-loader`?

Comment: without looking at the code, I'd guess that `awesome-typescript-loader` was probably importing the whole package under the hood while `babel-loader` is properly [tree-shaking](https://medium.com/@netxm/what-is-tree-shaking-de7c6be5cadd)